# gdb - check changed variables' values on next step

Tags: c, gdb

is there a way to check the value of **lvalue** variables without using the `print` command when debugging the code step by step, what I'm looking to do is the following:

If I have the following code:

```
> x = 5;
  y = 6;
```

when I'm debugging the code and I use `next`, I want **gdb** to display the value of `x`, that is the variable that changed in that instruction, I know I can watch the variable, but what I'm looking for is to be able to check variables on the fly without using `print`

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the display command:

```
(gdb) help display
Print value of expression EXP each time the program stops.
```

For instance if you display both you will get:

```
(gdb) next
4       y=6;
2: y = 0
1: x = 5
(gdb) 
5       return 0;
2: y = 6
1: x = 5
```